# is it possible to access a specific SceneKit node via its "ID" number

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am using SceneKit to make a type of block pushing game and I am trying to access a specific node that I interact with. I know I can use the nodes name but I am trying to access a specific node that has the same name as other reference nodes, its a pushable block that I need to make an array of its past movement so that I can undo the players actions. I have printed the nodes details to the console and each one has a unique "ID"

<SCNNode: 0x6000039ef300 'wall' pos(0.000000 0.500000 4.000000)

but I can't seem to then get access to the node using this "ID"

I can't find this documented anywhere so I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that looks like you can access it that way.  I wanted to do a similar thing awhile back so I remember looking for it.  I ended up using a naming scheme - like "panel_NNN-NNN" - that way I could tear the string apart and search for master-children relationships kind of stuff.

Comment: Did you use reference nodes or add copies of each node then name them manually? it’s a bit of an oversight on Apple if there is no other way to access them.

Comment: I wasn't cloning -  on create of any node, I have a shared global data area with some counter methods - getNext() so I always have unique names when they are created.

Comment: Can't you just assign it to an SCNNode variable?